# React JS Documentation (16.5)

Tags: reactjs

on react js official website. react js 16.5 documentation link is missing.
can any one please help here

> https://17.reactjs.org/version/16.5

Answer (score 0):

react js [official versioning](https://reactjs.org/versions/) states:

> **Note:** The current docs are for React 18. For React 17, see https://17.reactjs.org.

You can still access the `changelogs` but not the documentation if React version < 17.